# Powercenter Informatica REG_EXTRACT issue

Tags: regex, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I'm having an issue about **REG_EXTRACT** function in **Expression Transformation** in **Powercenter Informatica**. It can't capture first occurrence when the value to capture ends with special character (e.g: ı or İ).

Successfully retrieving the value of the `KEY2` as `VALUE2`

```
REG_EXTRACT('KEY1~VALUE1_ı|KEY2~VALUE2|KEY3~VALUE3|', '.*KEY2~(.*?)\|.*')
```

The value of the `KEY1` should be `VALUE1_ı`, but the result is `VALUE1_ı|KEY2~VALUE2`

```
REG_EXTRACT('KEY1~VALUE1_ı|KEY2~VALUE2|KEY3~VALUE3|', '.*KEY1~(.*?)\|.*')
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using

```js
REG_EXTRACT('KEY1~VALUE1_ı|KEY2~VALUE2|KEY3~VALUE3|', 'KEY1~([^|]*)', 1)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4FT5jk/1). The last argument (`1`) tells `REG_EXTRACT` to fetch just the Group 1 value.

The `KEY1~([^|]*)` regex matches `KEY1~` and then captures any zero or more chars other than `|` into Group 1.

Comment: It didn't work too, but I just realized a different scenario with your suggestion. Some of values ends with non special characters (in my case it's m) are not successfully extractable too. I'm starting to think the issue is about different representations of pipe characters. Copy pasting the original values to Regex checker tool successfully extracts.

Comment: @suphero Then try `KEY1~([^|￨∣⎸⎹│]*)`, and there are mor such chars. `❘`, `∣`, `⎸`, `⎹`‎, `│`... Can you please copy/paste the *exact* text you have into the question?

Comment: @suphero Please help us help you :)

Comment: Believe me I really need your help :). I can try it tomorrow at the earliest since I am out of work. Also, since the data contains personal information, I cannot share it without changing it :(. Thanks for your interest Wiktor.

Comment: @suphero I am sure the confidentiality won't be compromised if you share just the vertical bar characters  :)

Comment: I have checked the alternative pipes but problem still exists. My special character theory still exist since the value ends with "m" is "Katılım". Maybe Informatica localization settings is the issue. Maybe the encoded version of the "ı" character is the issue. The pipe in the source is: "|" (copy pasted value). I'm losing my faith in Informatica and trying to extract text from the Database.

Comment: @suphero I see, so it is a regular `\x7C` symbol, an ASCII pipe. Yes, the issue is not with the regex then. Just FYI, I check char codes [here](https://r12a.github.io/app-conversion/), there is a nice *View in UniVoew* option where [you can](https://r12a.github.io/uniview/?charlist=%7C) get a lot of information on the chars you need, and even find similarly named Unicode chars.

Comment: Thank you for your effort and the links. I'm taking note that I might need these links in the future.